# kendoui scheduler change header color

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to change those blu button color but I'm not able to find the correct selector (in my application I've got a site.css file that has all the custom css rules)

I've also search on the telerik's online reference for the kendoui scheduler but with no luck

[image]

Anyone can help me please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following selectors:

Views:

```
.k-scheduler-views .k-link { // For all the views
    background: blue;
}

.k-view-day .k-link { // For day view only
    background: blue;
}

.k-view-week .k-link { // For week view only
    background: blue;
}

.k-view-month .k-link { // month-view-only
    background: blue;
}
```

Date navigation:

```
.k-scheduler-navigation .k-link { // For all date navigation controls, including arrows, "Today" and the date picker
    background: blue;
}

.k-nav-today .k-link { // For the "Today" button only
    background: blue;
}

.k-nav-prev .k-link { // For the previous arrow only
    background: blue;
}

.k-nav-next .k-link { // For the next arrow only
    background: blue;
}

.k-nav-current .k-link { // For the date picker only
    background: blue;
}
```

Note that you can find all of these selectors in the "Elements" tab of the Dev Tools of any browser.

Check out the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
    <style>
        .k-scheduler-navigation .k-link {
            background: blue;
        }

        .k-nav-today .k-link {
            background: green;
        }

        .k-nav-prev .k-link {
            background: red;
        }

        .k-nav-next .k-link {
            background: yellow;
        }

        .k-nav-current .k-link {
            background: cyan;
        }
      
        .k-scheduler-views .k-link {
            background: blue;
        }

        .k-view-day .k-link {
            background: green;
        }

        .k-view-week .k-link {
            background: red;
        }

        .k-view-month .k-link {
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
  views: ["day", "week", "month", "agenda"],
  dataSource: [
    {
      id: 1,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Interview"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Meeting"
    }
  ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if I want to keep the exact layout (your button respect to kendo are smaller )

Comment: The size of the buttons isn't affected by the applied style. Did you try adding this style to your code? If you do, you'll see that the size doesn't change, only the color does.

Comment: Did you try this solution?